# Как сбросить display block?

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет , делаю квиз на swiper js, там есть 4 пункта , при выборе одного из пунктов включается display block и следующий свайп будет с этой информацией , но если я нажимаю назад и выбираю другой вариант то тот тоже становиться
display block и на следующем свайпе они в 2 стоят два блока друг под другом как убрать это ?

Спасибо за помощь.
Здесь краткий пример что я пытаюсь сделать , но только js не отрабатывает по клику

[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://web.archive.org/web/20200930000729/https://codepen.io/oldschool1705/pen/bGELavK)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это получается если вернутся и выбрать другой вариант
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://codepen.io/oldschool1705/pen/bGELavK не правильно дал ссылку вот

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не навешивайте dislay: block а добавляйте и убирайте класс, єто упростит задачу, а в самом классе меняйте display

```
function changeSlide(evt) {
    var dataForm = evt.target.dataset.form;
    if (document.querySelector('.d-block')) document.querySelector('.d-block').classList.remove('d-block');
  
    var form = document.querySelector("#" + dataForm);
    form.classList.add('d-block');
}
```

Ну и класс в стили

```
.d-block {
  display: block;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Rusic/pen/LYGQQLO?editors=0010

Comment: Спасибо большое, я только учусь учту это на будущее, спасибо за ваш вклад в моё обучение .